# How i can sort elements in queue?

Tags: c++

**my prof asked us to merge two queue in one ordered queue. How can I order elements in queue ?  I need to order result queue are I need to make temp queue ?
How i can do this? the implementation of the Queue is:

```
class QueType
{
public:
QueType(int max);
QueType();
~QueType();
void MakeEmpty();
bool IsEmpty() const;
bool IsFull() const;
void Enqueue(ItemType newItem);
void Dequeue(ItemType& item);
private:
int front;
int rear;
ItemType* items;
int maxQue;
};
QueType::QueType(int max)


{
maxQue = max + 1;
front = maxQue - 1;
rear = maxQue - 1;
items = new ItemType[maxQue];
}
QueType::QueType() 
{
maxQue = 501;
front = maxQue - 1;
rear = maxQue - 1;
items = new ItemType[maxQue];
}
QueType::~QueType() // Class destructor.
{
delete [] items;
}
void QueType::MakeEmpty()

{
front = maxQue - 1;
rear = maxQue - 1;
}

bool QueType::IsEmpty() const
// Returns true if the queue is empty; false otherwise.
{
return (rear == front);
}
bool QueType::IsFull() const
// Returns true if the queue is full; false otherwise.
{
return ((rear + 1) % maxQue == front);
}
void QueType::Enqueue(ItemType newItem)
// Post: If (queue is not full) newItem is at the rear of the queue;
// otherwise, a FullQueue exception is thrown.
{
if (IsFull())
throw FullQueue();
else
{
rear = (rear +1) % maxQue;
items[rear] = newItem;
}
}
void QueType::Dequeue(ItemType& item)

{
if (IsEmpty())
throw EmptyQueue();
else
{
front = (front + 1) % maxQue;
item = items[front];
}
}
int main(){
int item;
QueType <int> q1;
q1.Enqueue(15);
q1.Enqueue(20);
q1.Enqueue(2);
q1.Enqueue(41);
q1.Enqueue(17);
QueType <int> q2;
q2.Enqueue(10);
q2.Enqueue(41);
q2.Enqueue(8);
q2.Enqueue(4);
q2.Enqueue(1);
QueType <int> result;
    While(!q1.isEmpty(){
    q1.Dequeue.(item)
    result.Enqueue(item)}
    While(!q2.isEmpty(){
    q2.Dequeue.(item)
    result.Enqueue(item)}
```

help me please

Comment: it'll be a better question if you post what you have tried. we can guide you along. this isn't a site to do your homework for you.

Comment: @Ayat Khrisat It is unknown how your queue is defined and what methods it has.

Comment: @Ayat Khrisat If the queue has data member that keeps the size of the queue then you can apply merge-sort algorithm using intermediate queues.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your given 2 queues into 2 separate arrays. Note that those 2 separate arrays are sorted by their own. Now, you can simply merge the 2 arrays together to another array - `sortedArray` and from there, fill your final queue - `sortedQueue` with the elements of `sortedArray` in their order

```
array arr1, arr2
while(!q1.Empty()) {
    insertToArray(arr1, q1.dequeue());
}

while(!q2.Empty()) {
    insertToArray(arr2, q2.dequeue());
}
int maxLength = arr1.Length() > arr2.Length() ? arr1.Length() :arr2.Length()
array sortedArray;
for(int i = 0; i < (q1.size() + q2.size() ); ++i) {
    if((i < maxLength)) {
        sortedArray[i] = arr1[i] >= arr2[i] ? arr1[i] : arr2[i];
    } else {
        fillArr2ToSortedArray();
        break;
    }
}
Queue sortedQueue;
for(int i = 0; i < (q1.size() + q2.size() ); ++i) {
    sortedQueue.enqueu(sortedArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: see my queue implementation their is no size method

Comment: you can implement that one, it's no 'Big Deal', the idea is to know how many items there are in your queue

Comment: I am restricted just in this methods

Comment: Actually you don't really need that function. However, the idea which i presented in the code is what you're looking for. Try to understand it and then use the functions you have(i.e. `while !q1.Empty()`). This is a classic concept that you'll encounter more and more(recommend to read about merge sort)